# How to make my javascript code invalid after i change screen size?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to create a navigation bar. When the screen size becomes a certain size, I want the tab links to disappear and a button appears to make them expand. This is working as intended, however while I have pushed the button and I have the expanded list, if my screen size changes and increases above the threshold the changes still apply and I can't find a way to remove them.

The code:

HTML:

```
<nav>
        <div class="navList">
            <ul>
                <li class = "navImg"><img src="./Images/Logo (1).png" alt="Logo" /></li>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Collection</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Wholesale</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
            <button class="navDropdown">&#9776;</button>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

CSS:

```
.navList {
    display: flex;
    background-color: #002F63;
}

.navList ul {
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.navList ul li {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 1.7rem;
    margin-top: 2.5rem;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.navImg {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 !important;
    margin-left: 1rem !important;
    margin-right: 1rem !important;
}

.navList ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

.navDropdown {
    align-self: right;
    margin-left: auto;
    background-color: #002F63;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding-right: 1.5rem;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 813px) {
    
    .navList ul{
        display: none;
    } 

    .navDropdown {
        display: inline-block;
    }

}
```

Javascript:

```
$(".navDropdown").on("click", function () {
    var x = $(".navList ul").css("display");
    if (x === "none") {
        $(".navList ul").css("display","block");
    } else {
        $(".navList ul").css("display","none");
    }
});
```

I want the navigation bar to return to normal when increasing the screensize after I have pressed the button, but it remains as expanded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I probably have too much CSS; as you can tell I have a preference for kebab `my-class` css style names.

No need for jQuery here so I just used plain JavaScript to toggle a `show-me` class and put that in the media query where the width is narrow so the button "overrides" the media query that way.

Note I put a small font on the `img` so it did not look bad when no image was present.

I put some ugly borders on just to show what is where.

Converted the px to em and set the normal browser default of 16px = 1em

```js
var hamburger = document.querySelector(".navDropdown");
hamburger.addEventListener("click", handleClick);

function handleClick(event) {
  const navBlock = event.target.closest(".nav-container")
    .querySelector('.nav-block');
  navBlock.classList.toggle('show-me');
}
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.nav-wrapper {
  --nav-grid-min-size: 5em;
  --nav-background-color: #002F63;
}

.nav-wrapper,
.nav-wrapper * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.nav-container {
  min-height: 3em;
  display: grid;
  /* 4 columns- space left, menu, burger, space right */
  grid-template-columns: 1em 1fr 2em 2em;
  grid-template-rows: minmax(auto, auto);
  /* named areas just for clarity of what goes where */
  grid-template-areas: ". menu burger .";
  gap: 1em;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: var(--nav-background-color);
}

.nav-container .nav-block {
  border: solid pink 1px;
  list-style-type: none;
  grid-area: menu;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 1em;
  column-gap: 1.7em;
  min-height: 0;
  padding-top: 0.5em;
  padding-bottom: 0.5em;
}

.nav-container .nav-block li {
  width: min-content;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  border: solid yellow 1px;
}

.navImg * {
  font-size: 0.5em;
}

.nav-container .nav-block li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navDropdown {
  background-color: var(--nav-background-color);
  border: none;
  border: solid cyan 1px;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.nav-hamburger {
  grid-area: burger;
  margin-left: auto;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: var(--nav-background-color);
}

.nav-wrapper>.nav-container>.nav-block.navDropdown.show-me {
  display: flex!important;
}

@media screen and ( width > 40em) {
  .nav-wrapper>.nav-container .nav-hamburger {
    display: none;
  }
  .nav-wrapper>.nav-container .nav-block {
    display: flex;
  }
}

@media screen and (width <=40em) {
  .nav-wrapper>.nav-container .nav-hamburger {
    display: block;
  }
  .nav-wrapper>.nav-container .nav-block {
    display: none;
  }
  .nav-wrapper>.nav-container .nav-block.show-me {
    display: flex!important;
  }
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<nav class="nav-wrapper">
  <div class="navList nav-container">
    <ul class="nav-block ">
      <li class="navImg"><img src="./Images/Logo (1).png" alt="Logo" /></li>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Collection</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Wholesale</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <button class="navDropdown nav-hamburger">&#9776;</button>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could consider toggling a class on the `<ul>` element instead of applying CSS directly on the element. Using a class lets you apply the same CSS but then you can have it only activate within your media query constraint:

```js
$(".navDropdown").on("click", function () {
  const $ul = $(".navList ul");
  $ul[`${$ul.hasClass('open') ? 'remove' : 'add'}Class`]('open');
});
```

```css
.navList {
    display: flex;
    background-color: #002F63;
}

.navList ul {
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.navList ul li {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 1.7rem;
    margin-top: 2.5rem;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.navImg {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 !important;
    margin-left: 1rem !important;
    margin-right: 1rem !important;
}

.navList ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

.navDropdown {
    align-self: right;
    margin-left: auto;
    background-color: #002F63;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding-right: 1.5rem;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 813px) {
    .navList ul {
        display: none;
    } 

    .navDropdown {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .open[class] {
      display: block;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-v2CJ7UaYy4JwqLDIrZUI/4hqeoQieOmAZNXBeQyjo21dadnwR+8ZaIJVT8EE2iyI61OV8e6M8PP2/4hpQINQ/g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<nav>
  <div class="navList">
    <ul>
      <li class = "navImg"><img src="https://picsum.photos/48/48" alt="Logo" /></li>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Collection</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Wholesale</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <button class="navDropdown">&#9776;</button>
  </div>
</nav>
```